# Action Filters In MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, filter, action

I want to create an action filter in mvc that can be used in multiple mvc applications. Can we create **actionfilters** in MVC in a class library and **reuse** them in multiple mvc applications?

Answer (score 0):

According my study it is not possible to create Action filters in a class library and reuse them in multiple MVC applications